# appropriate international icon for "deals"

Tags: icons, symbols

We (like so many other startups) are developing an iPhone app that contains a "local deals" tab. (Discounts on meals at restaurants, etc.) I am trying to figure out what would be the best icon to use to mean "deals".

Some of ideas are the usual suspects: dollar sign/icons of bills and/or coins, a "price tag" with optionally some glyph emblazoned on it (percent sign, dollar sign, etc.)

I'd like to avoid using "$" since that's so US-centric. (or is it? is it a generally recognized symbol for "money" overseas)

EDIT:

Here's what I originally came up with:
[image: deal tag]

Comment: I like your original one!

Comment: Could you add a minus sign to your orginal one ?

Comment: Good suggestion phillip--I did try but it looked "funny". But logically it should probably have one.

Comment: Thanks everyone--for now I will keep the original icon and see how far we get.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're thinking in the right direction with the price tag, especially with a money sign on it (or a percent sign, to be more general, although I think the dollar sign is definitely recognized overseas. Other symbols could work, too - a thumbs-up, an exclamation point, etc.) I'd steer clear of the handshake, since it connotes a different definition of "deal," which refers to the arrangement between two people, rather than a sale. Your definition is more like "sale" or "savings" - and the specifically **red** price tag is a big hit [when you Google "sale"](http://www.google.ca/search?um=1&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&biw=1440&bih=797&site=search&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=sale&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=).

Here's an idea - does your app include localization for different currencies? Dollars in the states, Euros in Europe, etc.? It would make sense to do that if your app is going to be used for local deals - you'd want to show them in the local currency! Make a red sale tag one for each currency that you support, then you're good to go.

Comment: I like the local currency suggestion, however I think that will be quite difficult to implement properly. I'll post what I have if that might be useful.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a coupon, with a noticeable perforation line, maybe along these lines:
[image: coupon]

Answer (score 3):

I think a gold coin, price tag, or hand shake symbol would suffice. People recognize the dollar symbol but are turned off when its used to represent their money too.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an "index" icon which could clear tell the meaning from itself, and you also could use a "symbolic" way that might not indicate what that mean by the icon pic and need to teach the audiences in a long term way.